# Nvidia driver installed but not getting loaded

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04

Followed many links to installs nvidia on dell XPS 9560.
nvidia-390.77 got installed successfully and am able to login as well.
The issues I face is that, nvidia driver is not being loaded.

### journalctl -xb | grep nvidia

```
    anand@anand-XPS-15-9560:~$ journalctl -xb | grep nvidia
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glsi.so.396.45: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/nvidia-compute-utils-396.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnvidia-gl-396:amd64.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnvidia-decode-396:i386.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnvidia-ifr1-396:i386.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnvidia-fbc1-396:amd64.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnvidia-decode-396:amd64.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnvidia-gl-396:i386.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnvidia-ifr1-396:amd64.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnvidia-encode-396:i386.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnvidia-cfg1-396:amd64.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/nvidia-kernel-common-396.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/nvidia-kernel-source-396.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:55 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnvidia-encode-396:amd64.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:56 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/nvidia-dkms-396.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:56 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnvidia-fbc1-396:i386.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:56 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/nvidia-driver-396.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:56 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/nvidia-utils-396.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:56 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-396.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:56 anand-XPS-15-9560 ureadahead[297]: ureadahead:/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnvidia-common-396.list: No such file or directory
Aug 03 11:01:56 anand-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: Starting Fall back on nouveau if nvidia is not loaded...
-- Subject: Unit nvidia-fallback.service has begun start-up
-- Unit nvidia-fallback.service has begun starting up.
Aug 03 11:01:56 anand-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: Started Fall back on nouveau if nvidia is not loaded.
-- Subject: Unit nvidia-fallback.service has finished start-up
-- Unit nvidia-fallback.service has finished starting up.
Aug 03 11:02:08 anand-XPS-15-9560 nvidia-settings-autostart.desktop[2337]: ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
Aug 03 11:02:08 anand-XPS-15-9560 nvidia-settings-autostart.desktop[2337]: ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


anand@anand-XPS-15-9560:~$ dpkg -s nvidia-390
Package: nvidia-390
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: non-free/libs
Installed-Size: 20
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: nvidia-graphics-drivers-390
Version: 390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
Depends: nvidia-driver-390
Description: Transitional package for nvidia-driver-390
 This is a transitional package for nvidia-driver-390, and can be
 safely removed after the installation is complete.
Homepage: http://www.nvidia.com
```

Comment: Currently I switched to intel profile `prime-select intel` and everything works smooth after switching to 1920 x 1080 resolution with scale set to 100%. But if i change resolution to 3840 x 2160 with scale set to 200%, then the graphics rendering is not smooth and if an app opens multiple popups some popups does not show content and black overlay is been displayed.

Comment: Try doing a reinstall to see if it fixes it. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-390 --reinstall` then `prime-select nvidia` If it doesn't work, try to driver from Ubuntu main repo, latest version is 390.48, that works for me on my laptop with gtx1050